# jQuery $.ajax server converting to json

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery. My application is already built. I see two ajax methods used `$.getJSON()` and $.ajax(). What I don't understand is in case with `$.getJSON()`, the data received in success function is used directly as object.

But in case with $.ajax , I see the code
`var json = eval('(' + data + ')');`, why should we need to do this conversion and why is it not required for `$.getJSON()` method?

Below is the $.ajax() and $.getJSON() code:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ServiceUrl.SystemConfig,
    data: "",
    success : function(data) {
         var json = eval('(' + data + ')');
    }

    $.getJSON('/index', "",
    function(json, textStatus) { })
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Probably the Content-Type isn't set correctly? Or, probably the wrong function is being used to load JS content? Anyways without example responses we can't tell why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] )` method is a shortcut for

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

If you [read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), you would see that.

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON is a shortcut for setting the expected Content-Type to application/json in a $.ajax request, which tells jQuery to parse the response into a JSON object before returning it. This is really helpful when you know you'll be receiving JSON. $.ajax is more generic and therefore does not know it will be getting JSON unless it is specifically told to. This means the response from $.ajax is not pre-parsed, and you have to do it yourself.